# seaborn and pandas: regplot with one axis in log scale

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I want to plot variables in two columns of a pandas dataframe, and use the log of one of these columns. I could create a new column with the log but thought it would be easier to use a log scale.

This is what I got:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.arange(1, 10)
y = 10 ** np.arange(1, 10)
data = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': x, 'y': y})

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
ax.set_yscale("log")
sns.regplot(x="x", y="y", data=data, ax=ax);
```

[image]

Is there a way to fix this without modifying the input dataframe?

EDIT

As mentioned by Johan I could use logx and flip my axes, but this is not the plot I want. And in general, I was wondering if a function could be passed to transform the data in x or y in seaborn (not necessarily `log`).

Comment: Maybe `sns.regplot(x="y", y="x", logx=True, ...)`?

Comment: This is indeed a solution, but works only for the X axis. No such option for the Y...